# Apply a Function per Row of Sub Groups of the Data **Above** the Current Row

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, performance

Assume I have data in the form (As a Pandas' Data Frame):

| Index | ID | Value | Div Factor | Weighted Sum |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 2 | 1 |  |
| 2 | 1 | 3 | 2 |  |
| 3 | 2 | 6 | 1 |  |
| 4 | 1 | 1 | 3 |  |
| 5 | 2 | 3 | 2 |  |
| 6 | 2 | 9 | 3 |  |
| 7 | 2 | 8 | 4 |  |
| 8 | 3 | 5 | 1 |  |
| 9 | 3 | 6 | 2 |  |
| 10 | 1 | 8 | 4 |  |
| 11 | 3 | 2 | 3 |  |
| 12 | 3 | 7 | 4 |  |

I want to calculate the column `Weighted Sum` as following (For the $i$ -th row):

1. Look at all values from row 1 to `i`.
2. Sum values by groups according to the `ID` value of each row. So we have `k` sum values where `k` is the number of unique `ID` value from the row 1 to `i`.
3. Divide each sum (There are `k` sum values) by the number of elements in the group.
4. Sum those `k` values and divide by `k` (The average of the averages).

For example, let's do rows 1, 7 and 12:

#### Row 1

For `i = 1` we have a single value hence the sum is 2 and the average of the single group is 2 and average over all groups is 2.

#### Row 7

For `i = 7` we have only 2 unique values of `ID` above it: 1 and 2.
For the group of `ID = 1` we have: (1 + 3 + 2) / 3 = 2.
For the group of `ID = 2` we have: (8 + 9 + 3 + 6) / 4 = 6.5.
Then the average of averages is (2 + 6.5) / 2 = 4.25.

#### Row 12

For `i = 12` we have 3 unique `ID` values on the rows `1:12`.
For the group of `ID = 1` we have: (8 + 1 + 3 + 2) / 4 = 3.5.
For the group of `ID = 2` we have: (8 + 9 + 3 + 6) / 4 = 6.5.
For the group of `ID = 3` we have: (7 + 2 + 6 + 5) / 4 = 5.
Then the average of averages is (3.5 + 6.5 + 5) / 3 = 5.

It is easy to do with a loop but for a large number of rows it is inefficient.
Is there an efficient way to do so? Maybe using `apply()` or `transform()`?

**Remark**: The method should be feasible for the case of ~`1e7` rows and ~`1e6` unique ID's.

Comment: Could you possibly provide the code associated with what you're doing, would help with figuring out what you're trying to produce?

Comment: can you provide the full expected output?

Comment: @JonathanJoshua, The code and the data are much more complex. I tried to have the smallest and simplest example.

Comment: @mozway, I think that if you got the 3 examples you will get them all. If you're after a certain row, tell me I will add it specifically.

Comment: It's just it's easier to check the correctness of one's approach by comparing to the full output (no need to break down all other calculations)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do what you're asking:

```py
df1 = df[['ID', 'Value']].set_index('ID', append=True).unstack(-1)
df2 = df1.fillna(0).cumsum() / df1.notnull().astype(int).cumsum()
df['Weighted Sum'] = df2.mean(axis=1)
```

(Simplification of the last line based on comment by @Acccumulation.)

Output:

```
    Index  ID  Value  Div Factor  Weighted Sum
0       1   1      2           1      2.000000
1       2   1      3           2      2.500000
2       3   2      6           1      4.250000
3       4   1      1           3      4.000000
4       5   2      3           2      3.250000
5       6   2      9           3      4.000000
6       7   2      8           4      4.250000
7       8   3      5           1      4.500000
8       9   3      6           2      4.666667
9      10   1      8           4      5.166667
10     11   3      2           3      4.777778
11     12   3      7           4      5.000000
```

Explanation:

- Use `unstack()` to pivot, making unique `ID` column values into a level of column labels with the `Value` entry of each row in the column matching the `ID` value of the original dataframe, and NaN in all other locations
- Use `fillna(0)` and `cumsum()` to replace each column with its cumulative sum
- Use `notnull().astype(int)` and `cumsum()` to replace each column with its cumulative count (where NaNs count as 0)
- Take the ratio of the cumulative sum to the cumulative count; this is the cumulative average at each successive row of `Value` for each unique `ID`
- For each row, take the mean of the non-NaN cumulative averages across all unique `ID` values. This is the result described in the question.

---

Detailed intermediate results:

```
    Index  ID  Value  Div Factor
0       1   1      2           1
1       2   1      3           2
2       3   2      6           1
3       4   1      1           3
4       5   2      3           2
5       6   2      9           3
6       7   2      8           4
7       8   3      5           1
8       9   3      6           2
9      10   1      8           4
10     11   3      2           3
11     12   3      7           4
df[['ID', 'Value']].set_index('ID', append=True).unstack(-1)
   Value
ID     1    2    3
0    2.0  NaN  NaN
1    3.0  NaN  NaN
2    NaN  6.0  NaN
3    1.0  NaN  NaN
4    NaN  3.0  NaN
5    NaN  9.0  NaN
6    NaN  8.0  NaN
7    NaN  NaN  5.0
8    NaN  NaN  6.0
9    8.0  NaN  NaN
10   NaN  NaN  2.0
11   NaN  NaN  7.0
df1.fillna(0).cumsum()
   Value
ID     1     2     3
0    2.0   0.0   0.0
1    5.0   0.0   0.0
2    5.0   6.0   0.0
3    6.0   6.0   0.0
4    6.0   9.0   0.0
5    6.0  18.0   0.0
6    6.0  26.0   0.0
7    6.0  26.0   5.0
8    6.0  26.0  11.0
9   14.0  26.0  11.0
10  14.0  26.0  13.0
11  14.0  26.0  20.0
df1.notnull().astype(int).cumsum()
   Value
ID     1  2  3
0      1  0  0
1      2  0  0
2      2  1  0
3      3  1  0
4      3  2  0
5      3  3  0
6      3  4  0
7      3  4  1
8      3  4  2
9      4  4  2
10     4  4  3
11     4  4  4
df2 = df1.fillna(0).cumsum() / df1.notnull().astype(int).cumsum()
   Value
ID     1    2         3
0    2.0  NaN       NaN
1    2.5  NaN       NaN
2    2.5  6.0       NaN
3    2.0  6.0       NaN
4    2.0  4.5       NaN
5    2.0  6.0       NaN
6    2.0  6.5       NaN
7    2.0  6.5  5.000000
8    2.0  6.5  5.500000
9    3.5  6.5  5.500000
10   3.5  6.5  4.333333
11   3.5  6.5  5.000000
result with df['Weighted Sum'] = df2.mean(axis=1)
    Index  ID  Value  Div Factor  Weighted Sum
0       1   1      2           1      2.000000
1       2   1      3           2      2.500000
2       3   2      6           1      4.250000
3       4   1      1           3      4.000000
4       5   2      3           2      3.250000
5       6   2      9           3      4.000000
6       7   2      8           4      4.250000
7       8   3      5           1      4.500000
8       9   3      6           2      4.666667
9      10   1      8           4      5.166667
10     11   3      2           3      4.777778
11     12   3      7           4      5.000000
```

Comment: Could you explain?

Comment: Please see my updated answer for a detailed explanation.

Comment: Would `df['Weighted Sum'] = df2.mean(axis=1)` not work for the last line?

Comment: Yes, thanks for pointing that out, I've updated the answer with this simplification.

Comment: The trick is really nice. I wonder, it basically creates a new data structure where we have per line the values of the ID. For the case of `1e6` rows and `1e5` unique users we'll have a data frame of `1e6x1e5`, right? This will make it not feasible. Or am I missing something?

Comment: I see that you updated your question with the remark "The method should be feasible for the case of ~1e7 rows and ~1e6 unique ID's", which adds a new dimension to your original question. Fortunately, cumsum lends itself to processing chunks of input rows together with the values of the aggregates (cumsum of values and non-null `ID` counts) from the final row of the preceding chunk. So you could loop over say 100-row chunks and use the answer's logic on each in turn.

Comment: I am sorry for updating with the remark. I thought the scaling was implicit, it was a mistake. Is there a way to do it without the intermediate data (`df1` and `df2`)? Maybe something fats with Numba and looping?

Comment: You can elide `df2` like this: `df1 = df[['ID', 'Value']].set_index('ID', append=True).unstack(-1); df['Weighted Sum'] = (df1.fillna(0).cumsum() / df1.notnull().astype(int).cumsum()).mean(axis=1)`. Regarding the query on numba optimizations in your comment, this is outside the scope of your original question. Please feel free to post a follow-up question and drop a link to it in the comments here. Please also consider marking this answer as accepted assuming you agree that it addressed your original question.

Comment: I +1 and marked your question. The followup is at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72790573/optimizing-memory-allocations-of-pandas-code-to-process-rows-using-explicit-loop.