# Optimizing Memory Allocations of Pandas Code to Process Rows Using Explicit Loops with Numba Optimization

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, performance, numba

Assume I have data in the form (As a Pandas' Data Frame):

| Index | ID | Value | Div Factor | Weighted Sum |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 2 | 1 |  |
| 2 | 1 | 3 | 2 |  |
| 3 | 2 | 6 | 1 |  |
| 4 | 1 | 1 | 3 |  |
| 5 | 2 | 3 | 2 |  |
| 6 | 2 | 9 | 3 |  |
| 7 | 2 | 8 | 4 |  |
| 8 | 3 | 5 | 1 |  |
| 9 | 3 | 6 | 2 |  |
| 10 | 1 | 8 | 4 |  |
| 11 | 3 | 2 | 3 |  |
| 12 | 3 | 7 | 4 |  |

I want to calculate the column `Weighted Sum` as following (For the $i$ -th row):

1. Look at all values from row 1 to `i`.
2. Sum values by groups according to the `ID` value of each row. So we have `k` sum values where `k` is the number of unique `ID` value from the row 1 to `i`.
3. Divide each sum (There are `k` sum values) by the number of elements in the group.
4. Sum those `k` values and divide by `k` (The average of the averages).

For example, let's do rows 1, 7 and 12:

#### Row 1

For `i = 1` we have a single value hence the sum is 2 and the average of the single group is 2 and average over all groups is 2.

#### Row 7

For `i = 7` we have only 2 unique values of `ID` above it: 1 and 2.
For the group of `ID = 1` we have: (1 + 3 + 2) / 3 = 2.
For the group of `ID = 2` we have: (8 + 9 + 3 + 6) / 4 = 6.5.
Then the average of averages is (2 + 6.5) / 2 = 4.25.

#### Row 12

For `i = 12` we have 3 unique `ID` values on the rows `1:12`.
For the group of `ID = 1` we have: (8 + 1 + 3 + 2) / 4 = 3.5.
For the group of `ID = 2` we have: (8 + 9 + 3 + 6) / 4 = 6.5.
For the group of `ID = 3` we have: (7 + 2 + 6 + 5) / 4 = 5.
Then the average of averages is (3.5 + 6.5 + 5) / 3 = 5.

**Remark**: The method should be feasible for the case of ~`1e7` rows and ~`1e6` unique ID's.

As a follow up to [Apply a Function per Row of Sub Groups of the Data **Above** the Current Row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72776330/apply-a-function-per-row-of-sub-groups-of-the-data-above-the-current-row), I got a good answer yet it allocates a lot of memory in case the number of rows and the number of unique `ID` are high.

I was wondering if there is a way to create a much smaller auxiliary data using explicit loops while accelerating them using `Numba`.

The idea is to have similar or better performance while reducing the memory footprint considerably.

Comment: The new requirement (faster and memory efficiency) is implicitly included in the original question. I think this still counts as a repost to draw attention to the original issue, which has an accepted answer.

Comment: @MichaelSzczesny, I added it after edit after I saw the answer. The user who created the answer asked me to accept his answer and open a new one about optimization.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a benchmark showing the performance of pandas, numpy and numba/numpy solutions at various row counts (12 to 36,000) and unique ID counts (3 to 9,000):

```
rows 12, unique ID values: 3
Timeit results:
foo_1 (pandas) ran in 0.003095399937592447 seconds using 1 iterations
foo_2 (numpy) ran in 0.0003358999965712428 seconds using 1 iterations
foo_3 (numpy_numba) ran in 0.00018770003225654364 seconds using 1 iterations

rows 120, unique ID values: 30
Timeit results:
foo_1 (pandas) ran in 0.0024368000449612737 seconds using 1 iterations
foo_2 (numpy) ran in 0.001127400086261332 seconds using 1 iterations
foo_3 (numpy_numba) ran in 0.00029390002600848675 seconds using 1 iterations

rows 1200, unique ID values: 300
Timeit results:
foo_1 (pandas) ran in 0.01624089991673827 seconds using 1 iterations
foo_2 (numpy) ran in 0.009926999919116497 seconds using 1 iterations
foo_3 (numpy_numba) ran in 0.002144100028090179 seconds using 1 iterations

rows 12000, unique ID values: 3000
Timeit results:
foo_1 (pandas) ran in 2.391147599904798 seconds using 1 iterations
foo_2 (numpy) ran in 0.2884287000633776 seconds using 1 iterations
foo_3 (numpy_numba) ran in 0.1226186000276357 seconds using 1 iterations

rows 36000, unique ID values: 9000
Timeit results:
foo_1 (pandas) ran in 44.33448620000854 seconds using 1 iterations
foo_2 (numpy) ran in 3.0259654000401497 seconds using 1 iterations
foo_3 (numpy_numba) ran in 1.6273660999722779 seconds using 1 iterations
```

The pandas solution creates an intermediate dataframe that is `num IDs x num rows` in size. The numpy and numpy/numba solutions calculate results column by column, so they create a handful of intermediate 1D arrays of length `num rows`. The numpy/numba solution is consistently 2-5 times faster than numpy, and pandas is 2-10 times slower than numpy.

Upping the size a bit more gives the following result (where the pandas solution is commented out):

```
rows 120000, unique ID values: 30000
Timeit results:
foo_1 (pandas) ran in 6.00004568696022e-06 seconds using 1 iterations
foo_2 (numpy) ran in 28.882483799941838 seconds using 1 iterations
foo_3 (numpy_numba) ran in 38.77682559995446 seconds using 1 iterations
```

So it appears that there is a threshold above which the numpy/numba solution loses ground to regular numpy.

---

Full test code:

```py
import pandas as pd
# insert code to initialize dfInit here
print(dfInit)
'''
Index   ID  Value   Div Factor
1   1   2   1   
2   1   3   2   
3   2   6   1   
4   1   1   3   
5   2   3   2   
6   2   9   3   
7   2   8   4   
8   3   5   1   
9   3   6   2   
10  1   8   4   
11  3   2   3   
12  3   7   4
'''

def initDf(colMult=1):
    df = dfInit.copy()
    dfMult = pd.concat([df.assign(ID=dfInit.ID + 3*i, Index=df.Index + len(df)*i) for i in range(colMult)], axis=0).reset_index(drop=True)
    print(f'\nrows {len(dfMult)}, unique ID values: {len(dfMult.ID.unique())}')
    return dfMult
df = initDf()

def pd_foo_1(df):
    df1 = df[['ID', 'Value']].set_index('ID', append=True).unstack(-1)
    df2 = df1.fillna(0).cumsum() / df1.notnull().astype(int).cumsum()
    df['Weighted Sum'] = df2.mean(axis=1)
    return df
def foo_1(df):
    #return None
    try:
        return pd_foo_1(df)
    except (ValueError):
        print('overflow encountered')
        return None

import numpy as np

def foo_2(df):
    values = df.Value.to_numpy()
    ids = df.ID.to_numpy()
    uniqIds = df.ID.unique()
    aggSumsAcrossIds = np.zeros(values.shape)
    aggCntsAcrossIds = np.zeros(values.shape)

    for id in uniqIds:
        curCounts = (ids == id)
        cumCounts = np.cumsum(curCounts)
        curValues = values.copy()
        curValues[~curCounts] = 0
        cumValues = np.cumsum(curValues)
        aggSumsAcrossIds += cumValues / (cumCounts + (cumCounts == 0))
        curHasAppeared = cumCounts > 0
        aggCntsAcrossIds += curHasAppeared
    weightedSum = aggSumsAcrossIds / aggCntsAcrossIds
    df['Weighted Sum'] = weightedSum 
    return df
from numba import njit
@njit
def np_foo_3(values, ids):
    uniqIds = np.unique(ids)
    aggSumsAcrossIds = np.zeros(values.shape)
    aggCntsAcrossIds = np.zeros(values.shape)
    for id in uniqIds:
        curCounts = (ids == id)
        cumCounts = np.cumsum(curCounts)
        curValues = values.copy()
        curValues[~curCounts] = 0
        cumValues = np.cumsum(curValues)
        aggSumsAcrossIds += cumValues / (cumCounts + (cumCounts == 0))
        curHasAppeared = cumCounts > 0
        aggCntsAcrossIds += curHasAppeared
    weightedSum = aggSumsAcrossIds / aggCntsAcrossIds
    return weightedSum
def foo_3(df):
    values = df.Value.to_numpy()
    ids = df.ID.to_numpy()
    weightedSum = np_foo_3(values, ids)
    df['Weighted Sum'] = weightedSum 
    return df

foo_count = 3
foo_names=['foo_' + str(i + 1) for i in range(foo_count)]
foo_labels=['pandas', 'numpy', 'numpy_numba']
exec("foo_funcs=[" + ','.join(f"foo_{str(i + 1)}" for i in range(foo_count)) + "]")
for foo in foo_names:
    print(f'{foo} output:')
    #print(eval(f"{foo}(df)"))
    eval(f"{foo}(df)"); print("... output suppressed.")


# ===================== BENCHMARK with timeit:
from timeit import timeit
n = 1
for colMult in [1,10,100,1000,3000,10000]:
    df = initDf(colMult)
    print(f'Timeit results:')
    for i, foo in enumerate(foo_names):
        t = timeit(f"{foo}(df)", setup=f"from __main__ import df, {foo}", number=n) / n
        print(f'{foo} ({foo_labels[i]}) ran in {t} seconds using {n} iterations')
# ===================== ... END BENCHMARK with timeit.
```

---

**Space used:**

The memory of a pandas solution which pivots IDs is proportional to `num rows x num unique IDs`. By comparison, a solution that loops over IDs processing one copy of the `Value` column at a time uses memory proportional to `num rows`.

This means that 10^7 rows x 10^6 unique IDs or about 10^13 4-8 byte values (call it 10^14 bytes, or 100,000 GB) is not feasible storing the pivot table in program memory with pandas.

However, 10^7 rows of at most 10 1-D arrays of 8-byte values uses on the order of 10^9 bytes or 1 GB of program memory in the looping solutions (numpy or numpy/numba above).

Note that adding a nested loop over chunks of a fixed number of rows will allow us to cap the memory usage of most of the roughly 10 1-D arrays mentioned above, but we will still need to calculate at least 1 array (the result), so this will never give us more than a factor of 10 reduction in memory footprint.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I +1. Could you add analysis of memory allocation?

Comment: Please see my updated answer which speaks to memory usage, concluding that 10^7 rows with an arbitrary number of unique IDs is feasible with looping (though not with an in-memory pivot table with 10^6 unique IDs).

Comment: Does the updated answer address your question?